# Python 3, create program that calculates e with a user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

```
import math
N=int(input('Non Negative Integer:')) #User Input (iteration/sequence continue until it reaches N)
E=0
while N>1:
  A=N-1
  C=A+A/N
  N=N-1
  E=E+A+A/N
print(2+1/E)
```

So im trying to create a program in which it takes user input(N) and run the formula for e until it reaches the Nth iteration. I'm not sure wheres the issue is and i want it to look something like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLx1O.png]

Comment: So what is your problem in implementing this? Can you add your code in your question?

Comment: Use recursive function calls

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and "ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/DOjFr.png" reveals a really careless question. You want us to take care to answer, so please take care on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:

```
N=int(input('Non negative integer: '))
E=N+1

while N>=1:
    E=N+N/E
    N=N-1
print(2+1/E)

#> Non negative integer: 2
#> 2.7272727272727275

#> Non negative integer: 3
#> 2.7169811320754715
```